# What happens if you pick up multiple Beholder's Keys?

Tags: darksiders

I've noticed that sometimes you can find another Beholder's Key while you're still carrying one. Once I picked up three, but I once again had none once I used on a door. What happens to the other two? Do they return to their chests? If not, do some doors become inaccessible?

Comment: Did you manage to test this out?